# Find transfer function from system of equations

Tags: equation-solving

I have a system of equations, For example:

```
eqns = {a1 x + b1 y + c1 z == d1, a2 x + b2 y + c2 z == d2, a3 x + b3 y + c3 z == d3};
```

and for this I need to find `x/y` in the output.

This is just an example equation. The real equation may be larger with more variables, but I need `x/y` (transfer function) as the output.

Comment: I think you are abusing terminology here. A transfer function a ratio of the Laplace transform of the output to the Laplace transform of the input. And it is a ratio between one output to one input. But you have 3 equations given and there is not even time variable involved any where. Now it is possible to make a matrix of transfer functions (done for multiple input/multiple outputs system). But I have no idea what your equations represent and why you are using the term transfer function unless this is an `x'=A*b` system and you are shown the `A` and `b` parts only? more context is needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, let the desired quantity appear in the equations, e.g., name it the ratio $ r = x / y $, then solve solely for it, which can be implemented by a special syntax of [`Solve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html) as shown below:

```
neweqns = eqns /. x -> r y // Simplify
Solve[neweqns, r, {y, z}] // Simplify
```

---

For the new version of equations appearing in the comment

```
eqns = {gm V1 + Vout/Rd == 0, V1 == Vin - Vs, Vs == gm (Vin - Vs) ((Rs/2)/(1 + s Cs Rs))};
```

as mentioned in the comment, the number of the unknown variables should be the same as that of the independent equations, otherwise, it may not constitute a "well-defined" problem to solve (overdetermined or underdetermined).

Anyway, if now `Vs` is the 3rd unknown, the ratio can be found in the same spirit as above:

```
neweqns = eqns /. Vout -> r Vin
Solve[neweqns, r, {Vin, Vs}] // Simplify
```

The result is

> ```
> {{r -> -((2 gm Rd (1 + Cs Rs s))/(2 + gm Rs + 2 Cs Rs s))}}
> ```

which "happens to" be free of `V1`. And it is also true for an exchange `Vs` $ \leftrightarrow $ `V1`.

Comment: eqns={gm V1 + Vout/Rd == 0, V1 == Vin - Vs, 
 Vs == gm (Vin - Vs) ((Rs/2)/(1 + s Cs Rs))}. This is the equation I want to solve for $V_{out}/V_{in}$. Using above method I am not getting correct answer.

Comment: @MohitSingh So then what ratio do you want from these equations?

Comment: @ Αλέξανδρος Ζεγγ $V_{out}/V_{in}$

Comment: @MohitSingh Well what are considered as the knowns and the unknowns, respectively?

Comment: @MohitSingh Of course above code shall not work for your second version of equations, which do not contain `x, y` and `z` at all.

Comment: @ Αλέξανδρος Ζεγγ  Unknown variables are V1, Vout, Vin and Vs. Others are known variable.

Comment: @MohitSingh The number of unknowns now is larger than that of the independent equations. Are you sure of that?

Comment: @MohitSingh Well, I can see that now `Vout` works as `x`, `Vin` as `y`. So what works as `z` now?

Comment: Yes, equations are correct. The value of Vs can be found from eqn Vs == gm (Vin - Vs) ((Rs/2)/(1 + s Cs Rs)) in terms of Vin. That we can put in eqn V1 == Vin - Vs again the value of V1 can be found out in terms of Vin. At last, this can be put in gm V1 + Vout/Rd == 0 to find Vout/Vin.

Comment: @ Αλέξανδρος Ζεγγ Thank you for your help.